# How to find if a spark column contains a certain value?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following spark dataframe -

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   a|   1|
|   b|null|
|   c|   3|
+----+----+
```

Is there a way in spark API to detect if `col2` contains, say, `3`? Please note that the answer should be just one indicator value - `yes/no` - and not the set of records that have `3` in `col2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PySpark recommended way of finding if a DataFrame contains a particular value is to use `pyspak.sql.Column.contains` API. You can use a boolean value on top of this to get a `True/False` boolean value.
For your example:

```py
bool(df.filter(df.col2.contains(3)).collect())

#Output 
>>>True
```

```py
bool(df.filter(df.col2.contains(100)).collect())

#Output 
>>>False
```

Source : https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.contains.html

Comment: Hi @Anirban, if this worked, please consider accepting it as an answer.

Comment: It's better to use `.first()` instead of `.collect()`, since `collect` is not recommended for large datasets

Answer (score 2):

By counting the number of values in `col2` that are equal to `3`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.agg(f.expr('sum(case when col2 = 3 then 1 else 0 end)')).first()[0] > 0
```

Comment: as far as I can see, the answer here is incorrect. You are calculating the sum values via aggregation.

If you want to check if a column contains a value, you could filter the dataframe on that column and see if there are any rows left.

`exists = df.filter(col('col2') == 3).count()
if exists > 0:
  print('3 exists in that column')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `when` as a conditional statement

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df.select(
            (when(col("col2") == '3', 'yes')
            .otherwise('no')
            ).alias('col3')
          )
```